# Create as many rows as a value set on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, worksheet-function

I'm having a sheet where I have 2 columns : 1 with a number, the other 1 is just a string

```
1 | aaa
0 | bbb
3 | ccc
1 | ddd
```

I'm triing on another sheet to create as many rows as the number with having the string :

```
aaa
ccc
ccc
ccc
ddd
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need `vba`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a tough task, and I'm sure it can be done simpler. However, the first thing that came to mind was `TEXTJOIN`. So if your version of Excel supports this function you could utilize this. For example in `C1`:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,REPT($B$1:$B$4&"|",$A$1:$A$4)),"|",REPT(" ",LEN(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,REPT($B$1:$B$4&"|",$A$1:$A$4))))),(ROW(A1)-1)*LEN(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,REPT($B$1:$B$4&"|",$A$1:$A$4)))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,REPT($B$1:$B$4&"|",$A$1:$A$4)))))
```

This is an array formula and needs to be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Drag down...

---

This would also still work if you have spaces in your values:

[image]

**> Remark:** If the resulting string exceeds 32767 characters (cell limit), `TEXTJOIN` returns the `#VALUE!` error.